# How to select one row with max(select field) and another (specific field)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to select one row with max(select field) and another (specific field)?

Below is my code
1. Get to know max(select field) first
2. Then select all field within the row. 
but step 2 doesn't return any thing, wonder know why?
And is there shorter syntax for same result??
Thanks.

```
$gid = 1;

// get lid
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(lid) as lid FROM t WHERE gid = :gid");
$sth->bindParam(':gid', $gid);
$sth->execute();
$arr = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print $arr['lid'];

// nothing return??
$lid = $arr['lid'];
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE gid = :gid AND lid = :lid");
$sth->bindParam(':gid', $gid);
$sth->bindParam(':lid', $lid);
$row = $sth->fetch();
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in one step with this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.* 
        FROM t 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(lid) as lid 
            FROM t 
            WHERE gid = :gid
        ) AS x ON t.lid = x.lid";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':gid', $gid);
$sth->execute();
$arr = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. wondering is there something wrong with my syntax why the last line not print anything?  and in yours how to print that row? Thanks.

Comment: what is the dot means?  `select t.*`   `t.lid`  `x.lid`

Comment: Because I'm joining tables, I'm using the table-prefix to tell the query which table to select from.  t.* means all rows from the t table (vs. the x table, which is a derived table in a subquery from table 't', aliased as in the outer query 'x').  You don't need it in a single-table query because there's no chance of conflict.